# Insert JS script into head tag on Phenomic React website (Drift JS Codes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a website with **React.JS** I am not getting how to activate [drift chat plugin](https://help.drift.com/developer-docs/javascript-sdk#html_example) by placing drift js codes on the top of the  tag. Please give me some suggestions about the best practices to appropriately add it.

> I think I don't need to add any codes here for this. so let's keep it
>   simple.

Comment: Can you locate the `index.html` file in your React app?

Comment: No, I cannot. it's built on top of Phenomic https://github.com/phenomic/phenomic Library.

Comment: Do you have a *'Html.js'* document like this one: https://github.com/phenomic/phenomic/blob/master/docs/Html.js?ts=2

Comment: We have to deal with Helmet react component to inserting tags on the head.